# C array char* completly free memory during execution

Tags: c, winapi, char, malloc, free

im looking to understand why this script dont completly free his memory allocation.
The windows memory used chart drop just a little from these about 400Mb total allocated.
All the memory are free with an array of int, but not with an array of char*

How to do it right ? many thanks for your help...

```
void testAlloc() {
unsigned char error = 0;
char **arr;
char **buf;
size_t size = 1;
size_t idx = 0;
size_t nextIdx;
size_t newSize;

arr = calloc(size, sizeof(char*));

while(idx < 9999999) {
    nextIdx = idx+1;
    newSize = nextIdx*2;
    if(nextIdx > size) {
        buf = realloc(arr, newSize * sizeof(char*));
        if(buf != NULL) {
            arr = buf;
            size = newSize;
            }else{
                error = 1;
                }
        }
    if(!error) {
        arr[idx] = calloc(32, sizeof(char));
        arr[idx] = "sample text";
        }
    idx++;
    }

MessageBox(NULL, "stop before free", "", MB_OK);

size_t i = 0;
if(!error && arr != NULL) {
    while(i < idx) {
        free(arr[i]);
        i++;
        }
    free(arr);
    arr = NULL;
    }
}
testAlloc();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

> ```
>         arr[idx] = calloc(32, sizeof(char));
>         arr[idx] = "sample text";
> ```

You are allocating 32 bytes of memory and storing a pointer to them in `arr[idx]`, then you are overwriting that pointer with a pointer to the array represented by the string literal.  The dynamic allocation is leaked.  Furthermore, you invoke undefined behavior later when you attempt to free the space pointed to by the array element, because the pointer then stored in the array was not obtained from any of the allocation functions.

Presumably, you wanted to copy the contents of the string into the allocated space, instead of overwriting the pointer to the space.  For that, you want `strcpy()`.

```
        arr[idx] = calloc(32, sizeof(char));
        // Note: an error check really ought to be performed here
        strcpy(arr[idx], "sample text");
```

Comment: "*you want `strcpy()`*" - `strncpy()` would be safer, unless you use `strlen()+1` for the length of the `calloc()` instead of using a hard-coded `32`.

Comment: Waouh, you are very nice :) and so so speedy :D
I havent see that i made mistake on these pointer overwriting finaly...
Im learning C, and yes i have forgive the error test on the two calloc in this sample.
I done the len with strlen normaly, instead the hard coded 32.
And instead strcpy, i try working with memcpy.
Very very thanks ! it works ;)

Comment: Using [strncpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) is hardly any safer. It merely [exchanges one buffer overrun with a different one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050107-00/?p=36773). Choose `strncpy_s` instead, if your compiler supports it.

Comment: *When used properly*, **any** of `strcpy()`, `strncpy()`, `strcpy_s()` (not widely available), `strcat()`, `strncat()`, and various others will safely copy the contents of a string to a large-enough buffer and ensure its termination.  The details and complexity of proper use vary among these, as do the options and behaviors when the buffer isn't large enough after all.  Some of these will be more appropriate than others for specific situations, but I reject the proposition that any are safer than others in a generalized sense.